# ajax validate 2 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

i have 2 forms in one page

Html

```
<form id="form-step1" action="">
         <div id="fstep1">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Ich suche</label>
            <select name="produktgruppe" class="sselect"
                  data-validation="required" 
                  data-validation-error-msg="Bitte w&auml;hlen Sie eine Gruppe aus">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">B&uuml;rom&ouml;bel</option>
            <option value="2">B&uuml;ro- & Schreibwaren</option>
            <option value="3">Druckerzubeh&ouml;r</option>
            <option value="4">Geschenkartikel</option>
            <option value="0">sonstiges</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Genaue Beschreibung</label>
           <textarea name="beschreibung" id="beschreibung" class="stextarea"
        data-validation="length" 
        data-validation-length="min30"
        data-validation-error-msg="Bitte ausf&uuml;hrlicher Beschreiben"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Menge</label>
           <input data-validation="required" class="sinput"
                  data-validation-error-msg="Bitte geben Sie eine Menge / Umfang an"
                  type="text" name="menge" value="" />
          </div> 

          &nbsp;<br>
          <input type="submit" id="formsubmt" value="weiter" class="button" /></form>
         </div>

         <div id="fstep2">
            <form id="form-step2" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Umkreis festlegen</label>
            <select name="umkreis" class="sselect"
                  data-validation="required" 
                  data-validation-error-msg="Bitte w&auml;hlen Sie aus">
            <option></option>
            <option value="LO">lokal</option>
            <option value="RE">regional</option>
            <option value="LW">landesweit</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Ihre E-Mail</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="server sinput" 
                data-validation="server" data-validation-url="/ajx/check_email.php" />
            </div>


           <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Ihre Postleitzahl (Plz, nur Deutschland!)</label>
           <input data-validation="required" class="sinput"
                  data-validation-error-msg="Bitte geben Sie Ihre Plz an"
                  data-validation="length number" data-validation-allowing="range[00001;99999]"
                  data-validation-length="min5"
                  type="text" name="plz" value="" />
          </div> 
            &nbsp;<br>
            <input type="submit" id="formsubmt" value="weiter" class="button" /></form>
         </div>
```

Javascript

```
$.validate({'."
form : '#form-step1',
onSuccess : function() {
       $('#fstep1').css('display', 'none');
       $('#fstep2').css('display', 'block');
       return false;
    }
});

$.validate({
  form : '#form-step2',
  modules : 'security',
  onModulesLoaded : function() {
alert('los');

      $('#fstep2').css('display', 'none');
      $('#fstep3').css('display', 'block');


       return false;
    }
});
```

At first the first form should checked, after that and all is ok, the second one should check.

At the moment the second check already starts at loading the page and i dont know why.

Hope someone can help me for that.

Comment: One way is to put the second validation within the first validation onSuccess since this is an async calls. This is a narrow case. But for future development better use Promise https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: how i can add a onsucess event to it? my trys wont work. Why he ignore the "form" variable?